# Is it possible to mock a login with Tescafe?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, testing, testcafe, end-to-end

Scenario: I am using Testcafe and Vue and in order to test the app features I need to be logged in otherwise I am pushed to the login page.
I have made use of Roles which helps not to repeat the login process but is there anyway I can login without actually logging?

Is there anyway to test the inside of the app without actually logging in and making a real call? I always need to have a data available in order to enter the app but it doesn't seem ideal.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there anyway I can login without actually logging?

If there is, it's a huge security problem you have in the app.

If you want to work around this, the best approach would be to build such a feature on your test environment. But that basically means different code on the test env (or some if-else logic), which is not ideal either and developers won't probably be cheerful about it.

If you want to have this because you have so many tests where you need to log in and it takes time, perhaps think about what you could test on different levels (unit, api), leaving only some end-to-end flows to the UI level. That way you can save a lot of time.

Comment: Thank you for your answer pavelsaman! This sounds like a lot of work where there is a lot to do already. Not sure how to tackle this. Building a feature like this does require time and I am a junior learning testcafe so It will take a looot of time.
Much appreciation again Pavel.